# Page tab doesn't work unless I specify Canvas URL

Tags: facebook-page

I am trying to make a page tab but I keep getting this error

> Sorry, the application you were using is misconfigured. Please try again later.
>   Message for developers only:
>   To fix this error, please set your Canvas URL / Secure Canvas URL in the application Settings Editor. Once it has been set, your users will be redirected to that URL instead of this error page.

I then specify the Canvas and Secure Canvas URL's, but that turns it into an app rather than a page tab.

The debug tool doesn't throw up any useful information.